# $f(x)=x\left ( \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x+9}\right )$ is this continuous and differentiable at $x=0$?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

Do we need to take into consideration that the domain of $x$ is only $(0,\infty )$??

And Then only check the differentiability for $x>0$??

Also, $$lim_{x \to 0} x\left ( \sqrt{x} +\sqrt{x+9}\right )$$

$$lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x\sqrt{x}}{x\sqrt{x}}+ \frac{x\sqrt{x+9}}{x\sqrt{x}}$$

$$lim_{x \to 0} 1+ \frac{\sqrt{x+9}}{\sqrt{x}}$$

How do we proceed from here?

Comment: The domain is $[0,\infty)$. Your equation is well defined at zero.

Comment: To be safe, you must specify limit from the right, as limit from the left is outside of your domain at $x=0$

Comment: Is my function well defined at $x=0$? The term $\frac{\sqrt{x+9}}{\sqrt{x}}$ becomes $\infty$ , so isn't it undefined?

Comment: Indeed your function is defined at zero. $f(0)=0\cdot(0+3)=0$

Answer (score 2):

Continuity at $0$ is clear. Next you can certainly try and find the derivative at $0$ (some call it the “right derivative” as the point can only be approached from the right); since $f(0)=0$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=
\lim_{x\to0}(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x+9})=3
$$
(write $x\to0^+$ if you prefer).

In the image below, the function has the green graph, the tangent at the origin has the red graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem:** The product and sum of functions continuous at $x = x_0$ is continuous at $x = x_0$.

It follows immediately that the function in question is continuous at $x=0$ from the right.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{x( \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + 9})}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x + 9})$$

Which exists by the same theorem described above.

Answer (score 0):

The domain is $[0,\infty)$ and so your limit is kind of already able to be evaluated, even though it technically doesn't exist (a left hand limit is needed and doesn't exist). $f(x)=0(\sqrt{0}+\sqrt{9})=0$. However, it is not differentiable since the derivative requires the function to be defined in a neighborhood around the point, i.e. $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ which needs a left and right hand limit. As the function is not defined to the left, the limit doesn't exist and the derivative doesn't exist. This is true in general for an endpoint of a function. We can however look at $$\lim_{h\to 0^+}f'(x)$$ which I'll leave to you.